# SyncResult field usage for delays between sync

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I'm working on SyncAdapter implementation.
And was wondering - we have a parameter of type SyncResult in our onPerformSync method.
SyncResult contains field - delayUntil.
AS it stated in documentation - it is used for delays between syncs.
But, when I call ContentResolver.requestSync - it is ignored.
So, does anybody khow how to use it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some investigation and debugging I came to next conslusion:

- SyncResult.delayUntil affects SyncAdapter invocations triggered by ContentResolver.notifyChange
- ContentResolver.requestSync ignores this flag